# Jest Unit Test on Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jestjs

I am trying to test my Ionic app with Jest instead of the traditional Jasmine and Karma.
I can run simple test like

```
expect(1).toEqual(1)
```

and test passed with no problem.

The issue that I am having is testing services. I have something like

```
expect(CalculatorService).toBeDefined();
```

and test will result as passed indicating the service is defined. However when I tried to invoke the method of CalculatorService

```
expect(CalculatorService.add(1,1).toEqual(2)
```

results in

```
"TypeError: CalculatorService.add is not a function"
```

I know with Jasmine & Karma we need to inject the service. But I don't know what's the equivalent for Jest.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any support of Angular for Jest. The only article I could find was this: http://blog.mikereyes.me/2014/06/unit-testing-your-ionic-angular-app.html, but it assumes you're mocking the service instead of testing it directly.   Have you tried to console.log the defined CalculatorService to see what it looks like?

Comment: can you provide your code snippet

Comment: Your question is a little old but i just find this repo who did it: https://github.com/datencia/ionic2-jest-example